# Loop Problems vs Apply

Tags: r, apply

I know that the *apply functions are a more efficient method than looping when processing data - but am struggling to do so for one recurring situation.  Take this simple example:

For this data.frame "myTNorm"...

```
> str(myTNorm)
'data.frame':   4631 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ nc101_code: chr  "NC101_00003" "NC101_00004" "NC101_00005" "NC101_00006" ...
 $ D2_01     : num  5.67e-04 5.17e-05 2.50e-04 8.79e-04 8.61e-06 ...
 $ D2_02     : num  1.83e-04 1.26e-05 3.35e-04 5.05e-04 1.89e-05 ...
```

I want to simply replace the value of each cell for specified columns 2:6  with a normalized value (i.e. cellValue/sum(column)).

I feel like there should be a nice way to use *apply with some function to do this nicely, but can only get it to work as a for loop.  Can someone please share the proper syntax!

```
for ( i in 2:6 ) 
{
     myTNorm[, i] = myTNorm[, i]/sum(myTNorm[, i])
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you look around posts on Loops versus *apply questions, you will see plenty of comments and even full examples showing that *apply methods are not always better than `for` loops. For your question, `myTNorm[, 2:6] <- lapply(2:6, function(i) i / sum(i))` is probably the standard *apply solution.

Comment: @Imo I think that second part should be `lapply(myTNorm[, 2:6], ...)`

Comment: @Shape You're right, of course. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Something like `scale(df[,2:6],center=FALSE,scale=colSums(df[,2:6]))` might convey the intent nicely. This is just `sweep(df[,2:6],2,colSums(df[,2:6]),"/")`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading a good tutorial like this one: https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-apply-sapply-lapply-in-r/. Or, try finding similar answers and adapting your own code before asking a question here.

However, you can try:

```
apply(X = myTNorm[,2:6], MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) x/sum(x))
```